# Unable to cast object of type 'Dice' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do a dice game but for some reason this error occurs.

> Unable to cast object of type 'Dice' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Here is my code:

```
class Dice
{
    int result;

    public void DiceRoll()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        result = rnd.Next(1, 7);
     }   
}

Console.WriteLine("Player 1 Turn" + roll);
int enterscore1 = Convert.ToInt32(roll);

Console.WriteLine("Player 2 Turn" + roll);
int enterscore2 = Convert.ToInt32(roll);
```

Comment: what is the exact error you get? and how did the roll got declared?

Comment: What is `roll` variable?

Comment: I assume `roll = new Dice()` but I don't see the point of creating a `Dice` object. Just use a `static Random rnd = new Random();` somewhere in your code and just call `rnd.Next(1,7)` when you want a new dice roll.

Answer (score 2):

Some notes:

- You'd often use one of [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32), [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse), or [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse) when getting input *from a user* (i.e. as text) and want to get its numeric value (as an [`int`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/int) value).

  Here you have the bones of a `Dice` class which works with an `int` already, so there is *no need for conversion*.
- I would **strongly** recommend you don't try to implement [`IConvertible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible) like the message implies - that's not really what it's designed for.
- Note that for cases like yours, it's strongly recommended you have a single instance of a [`Random`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random) because the [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.-ctor) is

  > using a time-dependent default seed value.

  so making multiple `Random` instances in quick succession are liable to use the same seed. If you do this, because methods on the `Random` class are not threadsafe, you should [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) on some object to prevent multiple threads from calling its methods at the same time (as I do below).

---

There are several ways to do what you want. Here are a few:

1. Have a single instance of a `Dice` and roll it many times:

   ```
   public class Dice
   {
       private static readonly Random random = new Random();

       public int Result
       {
           get;
           private set;
       }

       public void Roll()
       {
           lock ( random )
               Result = random.Next(1, 7);
       }
   }

   public static void Main()
   {
       var dice = new Dice();

       dice.Roll();
       var player1Result = dice.Result;
       Console.WriteLine("Player 1 rolls: " + player1Result);

       dice.Roll();
       var player2Result = dice.Result;
       Console.WriteLine("Player 2 rolls: " + player2Result);
   }
   ```

   (try it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BEO04U))

   Notice that I've assigned a variable for each roll - this enables you to `compare` the results using `>` and `<` to find out who wins.
2. Have a separate `Dice` instance for each player:

   ```
   public class Dice
   {
       private static readonly Random random = new Random();

       private readonly int _minValue;
       private readonly int _maxValue;

       public Dice(int minValue, int maxValue)
       {
           _minValue = minValue;
           _maxValue = maxValue;
       }

       public int Result
       {
           get;
           private set;
       }

       public void Roll()
       {
           lock ( random )
               Result = random.Next(_minValue, _maxValue + 1);
       }
   }

   public static void Main()
   {
       var player1Dice = new Dice(1, 6);
       player1Dice.Roll();
       var player1Result = player1Dice.Result;
       Console.WriteLine("Player 1 rolls: " + player1Result);

       var player2Dice = new Dice(1, 5);
       player2Dice.Roll();
       var player2Result = player2Dice.Result;
       Console.WriteLine("Player 2 rolls: " + player2Result);
   }
   ```

   (try it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LOleo6))

   You can still do comparisons, but because you have different `Dice` instances, you could add your own constructor to `Dice` to, for instance, stack the odds in favour of one player (here I've made the second player's dice only ever roll 1-5).
3. Just have a static `Dice` class

   ```
   public static class Dice
   {
       private static readonly Random random = new Random();

       public static int Roll()
       {
           lock ( random )
               return random.Next(1, 7);
       }
   }

   public static void Main()
   {
       var player1Result = Dice.Roll();
       Console.WriteLine("Player 1 rolls: " + player1Result);

       var player2Result = Dice.Roll();
       Console.WriteLine("Player 2 rolls: " + player2Result);
   }
   ```

   (try it [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/i1EIAo))

   If you're never going to do anything fancy with the `Dice` and it isn't expected to have any state (e.g. roll different values, or know about previous rolls) and you *need* to have a separate class, this is how I'd do it. You don't need a constructor because `Dice` is [`static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static). Again, you can do comparisons with the two results.

Comment: Random is not thread safe. So if you create two different dice classes in two different threads (or more) you might get very strange results. If you are going to use a static random it needs to be accessed in a thread safe manner.

Answer (score 0):

If you declared roll as a variable of Dice class, your code should be

```
int enterscore1 = Convert.ToInt32(roll.result);

Console.WriteLine("Player 2 Turn" + roll);
int enterscore2 = Convert.ToInt32(roll.result);
```

Unable to cast object of type 'Dice' to type 'System.IConvertible'

This error means you are putting argument that has no IConvertible interface which is essential to Convert class methods.

Answer (score -1):

you need to include `int enterscore1 = DiceRoll();` and it would help to define the random variable as an integer within the dice roll method

Comment: Well `DiceRoll()` has a return type of `void` so that wouldn't work :)

Comment: you could add int in there instead of void